# Is there a way to know that a firestore realtime query is returning the initial data fetch vs. an update?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**I have the following query:**

```
let unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('threads')
    .doc(threadData.threadId).collection('comments')
    .doc(item.commentId).collection('replies')
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'asc').onSnapshot(async (snapshot) => {

      snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        if (change.type === 'added') {
          
         ... process the data

        }
    })
})
```

**What I need**

I need to know whether the 'added' docs are from the initial fetch for this query or if they have been added since the listener has been set. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly simple way to manage this is to set your own variable to track:

```
let isInitialFetch = true;
let unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('threads')
    .doc(threadData.threadId).collection('comments')
    .doc(item.commentId).collection('replies')
    .orderBy('timestamp', 'asc').onSnapshot(async (snapshot) => {
      if (isInitialFetch) { /* do initial fetch stuff */ }
      isInitialFetch = false;
      // ... rest of function
    })
})
```

Comment: This works great! I was trying to do this with react state like a dummy and of course the listener wont know about a state update. Setting a variable local to the listener did the trick. Thanks for your help.